# How to redirect from one controller to another?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-redirect

i have a problem with my application, PHP codeigniter app, im just new in using it. so here's the problem, i have a controller named, login.php, this method will do the process of logging in, after checking if the inputs are correct, it will redirect to a new controller, so its like, redirect("new_controller"). but when i test it, it will show me an 404 error. anyone can answer?

Comment: Hello there. Can you give us example code?

Answer (score 3):

You should include the `base_url()` or `site_url()` *(depends on your config)* to `redirect()` function:

```
redirect(base_url('your_controller/your_method'));
```

Comment: still, i cant access it, from the default controller, redirecting to another controller

Comment: @egt1993 Please show more detail about how you are doing that. I couldn't help more while I don't know the details.

Comment: Probably this is the best answer I found all around.

Answer (score 1):

Like hashem answer you can use the redirect() function although you don't need to use base_url() you just need to have a '/' infront of the controllers name like so

```
redirect('/controller_name/method');
```

You will need to autoload the url helper in the file 'application/config/autoload.php'

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```